# Unable to use Document methods after moving to a new page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, javascript-objects

I'm trying to make a Chrome extension that auto-searches the Libgen library. My popup.html asks the user for the title of the book. From my popup.js file, I am able to extract the name of the book from popup.html and fill it into Libgen's homepage and click the submit button. Once the search results load, I am unable to interact/access the page results using the methods of `document` such as `document.getElementsByTagName`. I am unable to set the background of each row red (my intention).

My code:

**content.js**

```
function make_rows_red()
{
  document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].click();
  setTimeout(function()
              {
                var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
                {
                  rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
                }
              },4000);
}

make_rows_red();
```

**manifest.json**

```
{ 
    "name": "book finder",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": 
        {
            "default_popup": "popup.html",
            "default_title": "book finder"
        },
    "permissions":
    [
        "tabs",
        "input",
        "activeTab",
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

**popup.js**

```
function query(title, author)
{
  chrome.tabs.create({url: "https://libgen.is/"});
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code: 'document.getElementById("searchform").value=' + '"' + title + '"'});
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file: 'content.js'});
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', onclick, false)
  function onclick () {
    const author = document.getElementById("author").value;
    const title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    query(title, author);
  }
}, false)
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label>Title:
    <input type="text" id="title">
    </label><br>
    <label>Author:
    <input type="text" id="author">
    </label>
    <br><br>
    <div style="text-align: center">
    <button id="search">Find my book!</button>
    </div>
    <script src="popup.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Put executeScript inside the callback: `chrome.tabs.create({url: '....', tab => { /* here */ })`

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the URL that I'll be going to, since it depends on the book title provided by the user. Could you be a little more explicit about which portion of the executeScript should go into the callback and what the URL should be specified as? Thanks again for your response.

Comment: It's your `query` function. Two of its three calls should inside the callback of the first call.